# How to deal with external DB in a Hyperledger fabric chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I have an operation with X meters, the number of meter may vary.

For each meter, I have to set a percentage of allocation.

So let's say, in my Operation 1, I have 3 meters, m1, m2, m3, I will assign 10% for m1, 50% for m2, and 40% for m3.

So, in this case, when I receive data from m1, I will want to check that operation 1 and meter 1 exists, that meter 1 belongs to operation 1, and get the repartition for my meter.

All those settings are present in an external DB (postgres). I can get it easily in Golang. Thing is I heard that chaincode must be deterministic, and it is a good practice not to have any external dependency. I understand that if the result of your chaincode depends on an external DB, you will not be able to audit this one, so the whole blockchain lose a bit of interest.

Should I hardcode it in an array or in a config file ? So each time I have a config change, I must publish my chaincode again ? I am not so happy on having 2 configs to sync ( DB + config file in DB), it might quickly lead to mistakes.

What is the recommended way of managing external DB connection in a chaincode ?

Answer (score 1):

You could place the "meter information" into the blockchain data store and query it from there?

For instance the application may be used:

- maintain the state of all meters, with what ever information they require. This data is written to the fabric state store, where is may be queried.
- perform an additional transaction that contains the logic required to query meter information and act accordingly

In the above case the chaincode will be able to update meter information and act on information stored via queries and subsequent action.

Everything is then on-chain, therefore it is accessible, updatable and auditable

Comment: Ok, I like it. But how should I manage RGPD concerns ? As I should be able to delete user info if needed, I can't insert meterID, I created a random UUID linked to meterID. In blockchain, I will insert UUID, while in Postgres, I will have the relation between meterID and UUID. If I need to delete user's data, I just delete postgres row. But in this case, I won't be able to avoid external DB? Do you see another way ?

Comment: If I understand correctly:
- user on postgres
- userId/meterId on postgres
- meter information on chain, with the ability to assign/remove a user.

If a user no longer assigned to the meter, remove the association on chain - the meter still exists, but is owned by nobody.

Only link between user info and meter is held on postgres.

Meter decomissioned, delete from world state or mark as decomissioned. It will always be in the chain, for audit, but not in the world state.

More complex scenarios are available using private data, but i think that would be overly complex.

Comment: It's not exactly that. There is no user here. It is more like; I can't write real meterID with associated data into blockchain. So, I need the data to be anonymized / deleted if the client requires it. It must be GRPD compliant. My idea is to generate a fake meterID to insert into ledger, and a correspondance outside, in traditional DB for instance fakeID => meterID. But I still have an external dependance here

Comment: can you not have a meterID on chain, but the user to which it is associated and their personal information off chain (postgres)?